# Search for quoted text doesn't include answers where text is quoted in title "unlikely word combination"

Tags: bug, search

After asking this question:

- [Searching for text in smart quotes in dumb quotes doesn't work? “test: text” “xtest xtext” "dumb quotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202417/225437)

I went to update some of the title of questions that I'd previously put smart quotes into.  I now realize that there's an even more significant problem.  If some string is quoted in the title at all, it can't be searched for *except* by using the smart quotes in the search interface.  Into the title of this question (I don't want it to appear in the body) I've put a quoted string, but when I typed it, I used normal dumb quotes;  I didn't use smart quotes.

Now when I search for this quoted text, I get no results for simply quoting the text, I get no results, nor do I get any results if I add the smart quotes to the query:

- ["unlikely word combination"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22unlikely%20word%20combination%22)
- ["“unlikely word combination”"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%E2%80%9Cunlikely%20word%20combination%E2%80%9D%22)

This means that if users try to post questions that *include specific error messages* as they're instructed to do, and they happen to quote them, we can't search for them.  If they appear in the body of the question, we *might* be able to, except that often times error messages are put into  in code blocks that aren't searched.