# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a "moot" flag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

And yes, I mean "moot", not "mute" although...never mind.

It seems like there are times when a question no longer requires an answer, but has not been formally answered and thus marked as such. For potential answerers to be apprised there services are no longer needed, why isn't there a "This question is now moot" element that could be clicked/pressed?

As an example, this question of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694934/why-am-i-getting-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-405-method-not-allowed

I no longer need an answer, as I've solved it myself, but not really in a way that I would want to mark the solution as an answer to the stated problem. At the same time, I don't think the question needs to be deleted; I would just like to mark it as solved, so that nobody has to read through the voluminous first part only to see that it is no longer an issue.

Comment: If you think it will be helpful to future users, why not just answer the question yourself and mark it as accepted?

Comment: Not directly related, but unfortunately, your error message only appeared in quotes, so it won't appear if you [search for the error message in quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22The%20remote%20server%20returned%20an%20error%3a%20(405)%20Method%20Not%20Allowed%22).  Those results are ordered with newest first, so your question from one hour ago would ideally appear first. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202612/225437). :(

Comment: So your edit 47 minutes ago to say "this was a misnamed column" is the entire answer?

Comment: Yes, that's about the size of it.

Comment: I have often wished there was a CFIT tag.

Comment: @ClayShannon edits like that in the question to express a solution are strongly frowned upon. The question body should be the question and the answer should be the answer.  Edits like that are relics for forums which we try very hard to keep out.

Answer (score 22):

> I no longer need an answer, as I've solved it myself, but not really in a way that I would want to mark the solution as an answer to the stated problem. At the same time, I don't think the question needs to be deleted; I would just like to mark it as solved, so that nobody has to read through the voluminous first part only to see that it is no longer an issue.

That doesn't make sense to me. Either

- You have solved the problem - then you can publish the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted
- or it has turned out that the question isn't a real question, the problem was related to something else, you made a mistake in your thinking  etc.  In that case, the question should most likely be deleted.

having a specific flag or close reason for a type of question that neither looks for community input, nor contains any useful information, seems pointless.

Comment: And yet here we are on meta, with a close reason designed for questions that don't appear to seek community input.

Comment: @Bolt HOW DARE YOU DILUTE MY ARGUMENT

Answer (score 7):

Some of the questions I've asked here had similar outcomes.  A few I've answered myself, accepted the answer, and they've been helpful to someone else along the way.

You never know if someone is going to have the same problem you did, and your solution could save them days of banging their head against the desk.

Comment: I noted on the main question, though, that it will be hard to search for this particular problem, since the error message is quoted.